# Overlap audio .m4a audio file Java

Tags: java, audio

I need to overlap two audio file (.m4a) into one .m4a audio file.
Is it possible ?
How can i do this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overlap?

Comment: One is an instrumental song and other is voice audio file. I need to create a new file from these.

Comment: @enfix Do you got any solution? me too need this

Comment: I didn't find any solution.